# WinJS "forEach" Undefined

Tags: json, foreach, uwp, undefined, winjs

am working on windows app(winjs) with navigation template, all am trying to do is when i open the app at the home.html page list of applicants/candidates should be loaded. here is my code i was working on. but it throes me with forEach is undefined

```
  (function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/startpage/startpage.html", {
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {
        // TODO: Initialize the page here.
        var titlesListGrouped = new WinJS.Binding.List().createGrouped(
            function (i) { return i.ApplicantName.charAt(0).toUpperCase(); },
            function (i) { return { firstLetter: i.ApplicantName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() }; }
        );
        var list = q("#ApplicantListView").winControl;
        list.itemDataSource = titlesListGrouped.dataSource;
        list.itemTemplate = q("#ApplicantTemplate");
        list.groupDataSource = titlesListGrouped.groups.dataSource;
        list.groupHeaderTemplate = q("#headertemplate");

       WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://localhost/applicants/processing/getapplicant.php",  })
            .then(function (xhr) {
                var applicants = JSON.parse(xhr.response).d;
                applicants.forEach(function (i) {
                    var item = {
                        ApplicantId: i.ApplicantId,
                        ApplicantName: i.ApplicantName,
                        clickFunction: function (args) { WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/details/details.html", item); }
                    };
                    item.clickFunction.supportedForProcessing = true;
                    titlesListGrouped.push(item);
                });
            });
    },

    unload: function () {
        // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.
    },

    updateLayout: function (element) {
        /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />

        // TODO: Respond to changes in layout.
    }
});}
```

and the html code

```
    <section class="page-section" aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div id="headerTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div>
                <p data-win-bind="innerText:firstLetter"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ApplicantTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div data-win-bind="onclick:clickFunction">
                <div class="appId" data-win-bind="innerText:ApplicantId"></div><br />
                <div class="appName" data-win-bind="innerText:ApplicantName"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ApplicantListView" 
             data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
    </section>
```

and this is my php which generates json data

```
    <?php

header('Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:*');

$database = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','tech_m');
$query = "SELECT * from `applicant_table`";
$rs = mysqli_query($database, $query);

while($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    //echo "Access Granted";
    $ApplicantId = $assoc['app_id'];
    $ApplicantName = $assoc['app_name'];

    $rows[] = array('ApplicantId' =>$ApplicantId ,'ApplicantName' =>$ApplicantName );
}
$response['rows'] = $rows;
$encodedfile = json_encode($response); 
echo $encodedfile;  ?>
```

please if anyone could help on this, it would be a great help.

Comment: For `JSON.parse(xhr.response).d`, why is there a `.d` part? Is it a typing error?

Comment: [i followed this example](http://www.codefoster.com/win8pagenav/)    @ElvisXia-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

> here is my code i was working on. but it throws me with forEach is undefined.

From your php codes, you return a Json object: `$response['rows'] = $rows;`.

So the JSON object has a property rows, which is an array. But in your JS codes,
you retrieve the arrary using `JSON.parse(xhr.response).d`, in which the `d` property didn't exist.

To fix the problem, you can simply modify `var applicants=JSON.parse(xhr.response).d;` to below codes:

```
var applicants = JSON.parse(xhr.response).rows;
```

I checked the link you posted. It didn't talk about the how the dataSource look like. So I think `JSON.parse(xhr.response).d` is a data array in that blog.

Comment: [try this link, it talks about d](http://www.codefoster.com/netflixstage1)   @ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: if i try to get json format of data, then it throws an forEach error, when i try to get xml format of data everything works fine but thr again problem rises, it does not bind the link to the div

Comment: All right, I get it. Could you please debug `applicants` that comes from `JSON.parse(xhr.response).d;` see what's inside. I guess `JSON.parse(xhr.response).d.rows` might work.

Comment: it also not working, throws the same forEach error   @ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: Have you debugged `JSON.parse(xhr.response).d;`? what's inside?

Comment: instead of json i tried to get xml. everrything looks fine but the thing is it loads the templated data into ListView but when i click the Listview item it takes the last item and navigating.